# windows - synchronous startup script custom message

Tags: windows, powershell, startupscript

On windows machine i have configured a GPO so that all startup scripts need to finish before login prompt appears.

During this time you can see "Applying computer settings" and a loading icon.

My question is: Can the text be modified during this script execution to inform the user ? Something like windows update updates the percentage progress.

Example:

```
Write-Host "Starting Application update"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host "Configuring Application settings"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host "Configuring Application settings 25 percent"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host "Configuring Application settings 50 percent"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host "Configuring Application settings 75 percent"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host "Cleaning up"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You can use the verbose option in group policy, this should then display what is happening during the startup of the PC and what it is doing rather than just saying applying computer settings.